# Awk code explanation: changing order of fields

Tags: bash, awk, field

I have a file a .txt file that has 14 columns. The head of it would look like this:

```
name A1 A2 Freq MAF Quality Rsq n Mean Beta sBeta CHi rsid
SNP1  A  T 0.05   1       5  56 7    8    9    11  12  rs1
SNP2  T  A 0.05   1       6  55 7    8    9    11  12  rs2
```

I want to put the last column in the first position. I wasn't sure what was the most efficient way of doing this, but I came across this, inspiring myself from other posts:

```
awk '{$0=$NF FS$0; $14=""}1' file.txt | head
```

I obtained this, which I think works:

```
rsid    name A1 A2 Freq MAF Quality Rsq n Mean Beta sBeta CHi 
rs1     SNP1  A  T 0.05   1       5  56 7    8    9    11  12
rs2     SNP2  T  A 0.05   1       6  55 7    8    9    11  12
```

I am struggling though to understand what exactly the code does.

- I know that NF is the field count of the line being processed
- I know that FS is the field seperator

So how can my code work exactly? I just don't really understand how saying that $0 (the whole line) is equal to NF and saying FS$0 (not sure what this means) ends up with the last field now being first. I do realise that $14="" is not written, you end up with 2 rsid columns, one at the start and one at the end.

I'm quite new to using awk so if there is an easier way to achieve this, I would happily go for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through following and let me know if this helps you on same.

```
awk '{
$0=$NF FS$0;   ##Re-creating current line by mentioning $NF(last field value), FS(field separator, whose default value is space) then current line value.
$14=""         ##Now in current line(which is edited above by having last field value to very first) nullifying the last(14th field) here, you could use $NF here too(in case your Input_file have only 14 fields.
}
1              ##1 means we are making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action so by default print action will happen.
' file.txt     ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: So if I understand, $0=$NF FS$0 means: "make the last field equal to $0 (your whole line) and then use $0 has your field separator?" . Sorry, it just doesn't seem very instinctive. I think I understand but I'm not sure

Comment: read the equal sign as assignment.  Means set the new `$0` as the last field + field separator + old line.  It's the same concept in most (all?) programming languages.

Comment: Ah I see yes. I think i got confused by FS$0. From what I can see in my terminal if you write $0=$NF FS $0 its the same. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's only explaining part of what's going on here and part of what's not explained is the negatives to doing it this way (re-splitting $0, recompiling $0, trailing blanks, change of format).

Answer (score 2):

might be easier with `sed`

```
sed -E 's/(.*)\s(\S+)$/\2 \1/' file
```

match the last field and the rest of the line, print it reverse order.

`\s` is shorthand for whitespace character, equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\f]`.
`\S` is the negation of `\s`, for non-whitespace.  POSIX equivalent of `\s` is `[:space:]`.  If your `sed` doesn't support the shorthand notation or you want full portability you may need to use one of the equivalent forms.

Comment: You should mention that's GNU sed only for `\s` and `\S`.